# Outlook Button in Ribbon for saving mail (incoming and outgoing) to nominated destination in new folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to create a button in Outlook that saves an incoming mail in a folder named:

"yyyymmdd - {sender's initials} - {email subject}".

Similarly, I need a button for outgoing mail that needs to be saved in a folder named:

"yyyymmdd - {email subject}".

Since I work in a variety of directories, a user input will be required to specify the project number where the relevant mail needs to go, ie:

C:\Users\User.Name{project_name_input}.

I tried some VBA scripts, but I am not good at it. I haven't gotten close to a solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this by using some script found at the link below and some modifications to make it work the way I wanted on my machine:

https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/save-selected-message-file/

The script:

```
Option Explicit
  
Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
  Dim ShellApp As Object
  Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
 BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)
 
 On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
 On Error GoTo 0
 
 Set ShellApp = Nothing
    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
        Case Is = ":"
            If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
        Case Is = "\"
            If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
        Case Else
            GoTo Invalid
    End Select
 Exit Function
 
Invalid:
 BrowseForFolder = False
End Function

Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg()

  Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim objItem As Object
  Dim sPath As String
  Dim dtDate As Date
  Dim sName As String
  Dim enviro As String
  Dim mSender As String
  Dim sendName As String
  Dim sendSurname As String
  Dim strFolderpath As String
  Dim fName As String
  Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
  Dim i As Long
  Dim lngCount As Long
  Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
  Dim StrFile As String

  
  
    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    strFolderpath = BrowseForFolder(enviro)
   For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
   If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
    Set oMail = objItem

   
  sName = oMail.Subject
  sName = Replace(sName, "FW: ", "")
  sName = Replace(sName, "RE: ", "")
  
  ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"
  mSender = oMail.Sender
  sendName = Split(mSender)(0)
  sendName = Left(sendName, 1)
  sendSurname = Split(mSender)(1)
  sendSurname = Left(sendSurname, 1)

 
  dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
  
  fName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & " - " & sendName & sendSurname & " - " & sName
    
  sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & " - " & sName & ".msg"
    


    CreateIncomeFolder strFolderpath, fName
    sPath = strFolderpath & fName & "\"
    
  Debug.Print sPath & sName
  oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
  
  End If
  Next
  
  Set objOL = Outlook.Application
  Set objItem = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Set objAttachments = objItem.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
         
    If lngCount > 0 Then
     
        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
            If objAttachments.Item(i).Size > 10000 Then
            StrFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
            Debug.Print StrFile
            StrFile = sPath & StrFile
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile StrFile
            End If

    Next i
    End If
  
  
End Sub


 Public Sub SaveOutogingMessageAsMsg()
  Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim objItem As Object
  Dim sPath As String
  Dim dtDate As Date
  Dim sName As String
  Dim enviro As String
  Dim mSender As String
  Dim strFolderpath As String
  Dim fName As String

    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    strFolderpath = BrowseForFolder(enviro)
   For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
   If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
    Set oMail = objItem
   
  sName = oMail.Subject
  sName = Replace(sName, "FW: ", "")
  sName = Replace(sName, "RE: ", "")
  ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"
  mSender = oMail.Sender
  sName = Replace(sName, "FW- ", "")
  sName = Replace(sName, "RE- ", "")
  
  
 
  dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
  
  fName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & " - " & sName
    
  sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & " - " & sName & ".msg"
    


    CreateFolder strFolderpath, fName
    sPath = strFolderpath & fName & "\"
    
  Debug.Print sPath & sName
  oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG


  
  End If
  Next
  
End Sub
 
 
Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
  

End Sub


Sub CreateFolder(strFolderpath As String, fName As String)
    On Error GoTo eh
        MkDir strFolderpath & fName
        Exit Sub
eh:
    MsgBox "Message has already been saved", vbOKOnly
    
End Sub


Sub CreateIncomeFolder(strFolderpath As String, fName As String)
    On Error GoTo eh
        MkDir strFolderpath & fName
        Exit Sub
eh:
    MsgBox "Message has already been saved", vbOKOnly
    
End Sub
```